# Find the size of the area (triangle in a trapezoid)

Tags: geometry

Can anyone please help me to solve this task? The area "F" has to be found.

I thought I could find the size of the area of the trapezoid and then subtract the size of the two triangles. But I cannot find the size of the triangles.
The trapezoid is 5 cm* 11cm, divided thorugh 2 and then all together * 7
makes then 192.5 square centimeters.

[image]

Comment: where is M  point  located?random place?

Comment: Maybe $M$ as in "midpoint"?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I think it´s midpoint. But it doesnt say that in the task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Area of trapezium is $\cfrac12(5+11)\cdot 7$

Area of the upper and lower triangles are $\cfrac 12 \cdot 5\cdot a$ and $\cfrac12 \cdot 11 \cdot b$ with heights $a$ and $b$ respectively such that  $a+b=7$
$$[F]=\cfrac12(5+11)\cdot 7-\cfrac 12 \cdot 5\cdot a-\cfrac12 \cdot 11 \cdot b$$ Unless $M$ is a special (known or fixed) point, there are several solutions for the area of $F$.

**If** $M$ is a midpoint then $a=b=3.5 \text{ cm}$ and $[F]=28 \text{ cm}^2$

Comment: by the way  is  7cm  length of  left side?

Comment: $7$ cm is the height of the trapezium

Comment: i doubt that given information is not enough to solve this problem,for  triangles we dont have enough information about their lengths,which makes  nonsens  in solving this problem

Comment: @dato you're right, the given information is not enough

Comment: Sometimes introducing the right variable is part of problem solving... Simplified area of F is $35/2+3\cdot a$, with same notation (and same method) as "merge me".

Comment: Given data is not sufficient to solve this problem. Since the shaded triangle is oblique and not resting on either of the parallel sides makes us dependent on additional data.

Comment: okay well I was just thinking about HOW to solve. the 18 sqaure-centimeters are the right answer (it says so on my sheed). so I thank you very very much for solving this problem. I understand the thought with the hights of the triangle now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Call the vertices of the trapezoid $A,B,C,D$. The labelling goes counterclockwise, and $A$ is at the lower left corner.

Draw line $MN$ parallel to $AB$, and meeting $BC$ at $N$.

Our region is made up of two triangles $MBN$ and $MNC$.  If we view them as having base $MN$, then the **sum** of their heights is $7$.  Thus if $MN=z$, then the area of the shaded triangle is $\dfrac{7z}{2}$.

We cannot find an explicit numerical answer without making some assumptions. Suppose that $M$ divides the line segment $AD$ in the ratio $s:t$. Then 
$$z=MN=\frac{11t+5s}{s+t}.$$
In particular, if $M$ is the *midpoint* of $AD$, as the symbol $M$ perhaps suggests, then we can take $s=t=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is the midpoint of the side it's on, then the horizontal width at that altitude is $\frac{5+11}{2}=8$. The areas of both the top and the bottom halves of $F$ are $\frac12\cdot8\cdot\frac72$, so the whole area is $8\cdot\frac72=28\text{ cm}^2$.

**Justification:**

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

Assume $\overline{AB}\,\|\,\overline{DC}\,\|\,\overline{MN}$ and $M$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AD}$. By similar triangles, $|\overline{MP}|=\frac12|\overline{AB}|$ and $|\overline{PN}|=\frac12|\overline{DC}|$. Thus, $|\overline{MN}|=\frac12\left(|\overline{AB}|+|\overline{DC}|\right)$.

The sum of the altitudes of $\triangle BMN$ and $\triangle CMN$ on base $\overline{MN}$ is $7$. Thus, $|F|$, the sum of the areas of the triangles, is half the sum of the altitudes $\times$ the base $=\frac12\cdot7\cdot\frac12(5+11)=28$.